# Scala 3 Support For IntelliJ Community Edition

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is there a Scala 3 support available for IntelliJ Community Edition? I have the Scala plugin installed, but somehow when I was trying to set up the Scala SDK for my project, Scala 3 does not show up in the List (see image). Any ideas as to how I can have Scala 3 enabled?

[image]

Comment: What IDE version do you use?

Comment: 2020.1.4 is what I currently have!

Comment: You may need to get the later IDE release version to get Scala 3 support.

Comment: I kind of guessed it, but as I was doing it, I ran out of space on my Ubuntu machine. Cleaning up now to install the latest version of the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pressing `Download` button:

[image]

Select needed Scala SDK version in the dropdown:

[image]

[image]

Press "Ok", wait for download to finish and voilà (at least it worked for me using the latest version of IDE):

[image]